# Array of css files being requested

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7, application-cache

Is there anyway to get an array of stylesheet being requested by the site. Like in module stage of loading.
The point is that i am making application cache for drupal site, and (captain obvious) i need css files also to be downloaded. 
Drupal add's hahs(?) automaticly to some css and js files and i dont even know how, and i dont know how to turn it off, and there are over 15 css files. i could aggregate them, but still i am not able to get file name into variable or db.

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of research, i managed to go look from api, and yea, there was drupal_get_css hook, that helped a lot. Then there was another problem. Dummy string, You know the ?=aslkd thing after filename. I strugeled sometime with it, and then i decided to turn it off. Now kid's, never do that! NEVER! I lost alot of my styles and things got broken. 
I got desperate, and went to dig in to advgg's module and searched what i can find from there.
I got both js and css file from that module. Just go and find advagg_merge_plans and then
try this   dpm($css_js_groups['0']['filepath']); with devel module, and wait for the magig!
Hope i saved some one's day of googling